# (Postgresql) How to convert an emoji (or emoticon) to its unicode representation

Tags: postgresql, emoji

Currently I am using python to get an emojis unicode representation.

I want to be able to do this using postgresql. Example:

```
messageText
----------
```

```
select unicodeValue(messageText) from table where messageText = '';

Result: 'U+1F600'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that the database encoding is UTF-8, but that is a requirement anyway if you want to represent such strange characters:

```
SELECT to_hex(ascii(''));

 to_hex 
--------
 1f600
(1 row)
```